# Continuous integration and deployment of Node.js application on Bamboo

Tags: node.js, continuous-integration, npm, bower, bamboo

The application I want to implement continuous deployment on Bamboo has `node modules` and `bower component` dependencies. On the bamboo server nodejs, npm have been installed.

There are only three tasks on default job:

1. Source Code Checkout
2. Build dependencies:

   ```
   npm install
   bower install
   ```
3. Deploy to the staging server

The problem is on the second task, bamboo fails with the message "No failed tests found, a possible compilation error occurred." I don't even run any tests.

The log file is not explanatory at all:

> Starting task 'Build dependencies' of type 'com.atlassian.bamboo.plugins.scripttask:task.builder.script'
>
> Failing task since return code of [/bin/sh /home/ubuntu/bamboo-installation/temp/WEB-WEB-JOB1-8-ScriptBuildTask-4430338079602360707.sh] was 1 while expected 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I solved the problem. The issue was the [wrong node](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/hamradio/node) (which obviously messed things up) was installed on the bamboo server. Uninstalled the wrong one and everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Good to see you solved it.

There is a setup I use and which could prevent further problems with CI:

```
export npm_config_prefix=.npm/
export PATH=.npm/bin:$PATH
export CI=true
npm install -g bower
bower install
npm install
```

This installs *bower* (and others like grunt-cli if you want) in your project folder so you can e.g. have a specific version, sets `CI=true` as advised in *bower* docs, and then installs all dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Bamboo AMI originally have npm version 1.4.28 installed and you are probably using a more recent version on you development environment. I had the same issue and resolved it by creating a script task to update npm version on the very beginning of my build process. Here is the script:

```
# update npm
curl -O -L https://npmjs.org/install.sh
chmod +x install.sh
sudo PATH=$PATH:/opt/node-0.10/bin ./install.sh
```